# How to get current date time of the system in seconds

Tags: c++

How can I get current date time of the systems in seconds in C++?

I tried this one:

```
struct tm mytm = { 0 };
time_t result;

result = mktime(&mytm);

printf("%lld\n", (long long) result);
```

but I got: -1?

Comment: Current date time in seconds since 1.1.1970?  Like `time(0)`?

Comment: yes current date time in seconds since 1.1.1970

Comment: @Zeta That's not really portable.  In theory, at least, `time_t` can be a `double`, and there's certainly nothing which would require its numerical value to be the number of seconds since 00:00:00 1.1.1970 (although this is a frequent choice of Unix implementations).

Comment: @JamesKanze: `time_t` is *required* to represents seconds [by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/sys/types.h.html), so this is not just a "frequent choice"... This is mandatory for POSIX systems.

Comment: @ybungalobill But it's not required to be an integral type, and there's no requirement that the epoch be 1.1.1970.  (In C or C++, of course, there's not even a requirement that the representation be seconds.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: [Epoch *is* required to be 1970-01-01](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html) and [`time()` *is* required to return the number of seconds since Epoch](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/time.html). You are right that `time_t` need not be integral, but it is not a big deal in OPs case.

Answer (score 22):

```
/* time example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t seconds;

  seconds = time (NULL);
  printf ("%ld seconds since January 1, 1970", seconds);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Upvoting this, but in practice `time_t` may be a floating point type, so a cast is needed.

Comment: If `time_t` does not match `long int`, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: [This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-function-in-c/) shows almost the same example with more explanation: `time_t time(time_t *second)` _"The time() function is defined in time.h (ctime in C++) header file. This function returns the time since 00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 1970 (Unix timestamp) in seconds. **If `second` is not a null pointer, the returned value is also stored in the object pointed to by second.**"_

Answer (score 13):

C++11 version, which ensures that the representation of ticks is actually an integral:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <type_traits>

std::chrono::system_clock::rep time_since_epoch(){
    static_assert(
        std::is_integral<std::chrono::system_clock::rep>::value,
        "Representation of ticks isn't an integral value."
    );
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now).count();
}

int main(){
    std::cout << time_since_epoch() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:
I hope it will work for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main( )
{
   // current date/time based on current system
time_t now = time(0);

 // convert now to string form
char* dt = ctime(&now);

cout << "The local date and time is: " << dt << endl;

// convert now to tm struct for UTC
tm *gmtm = gmtime(&now);
dt = asctime(gmtm);
cout << "The UTC date and time is:"<< dt << endl;
}
```

Comment: thanks but how can I get date time in seconds since 1.1.1970?

Comment: @olidev Portably (i.e. guaranteed by the C++ standard), you can't.  Practically, all major systems represent `time_t` as an integral type with the number of seconds since the "epoque".  Just add or subtract the difference in seconds between the "epoque" of the system and the epoque you want.  (Most Unix based systems use 00:00:00 01 Jan. 1970 as the epoque, so the difference would be 0.)

Comment: @Nim A spelling error.  ("epoque" would be the French spelling.  And I've worked mainly in France.)

Answer (score 3):

possibly a simpler version of example provided by @Zeta

```
time_t time_since_epoch()
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    return std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t( now );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using below function with few minor enhancements but as other have suggested definition of epoch might not be portable. For GCC it returns seconds as double value since Unix epoch but in VC++ it returns value since machine boot time. If your goal is just to get some value to do diff between two timestamps without persisting and sharing them, this should be ok however. If you need to persist or share  timestamps then I would suggest to explicitly subtract some epoch from now() to get the duration object to be portable.

```
//high precision time in seconds since epoch
static double getTimeSinceEpoch(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point* t = nullptr)
{
    using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    return std::chrono::duration<double>((t != nullptr ? *t : Clock::now() ).time_since_epoch()).count();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give the current date/time in seconds,

```
#include <time.h>
time_t timeInSec;
time(&timeInSec);
PrintLn("Current time in seconds : \t%lld\n", (long long)timeInSec);
```